# Portet Communication between two pages in webcenter portal

Tags: oracle-adf, webcenter

I have two portlets(A and B) in two different pages, In first page, the portlet A contain a two buttons(calculate and next) on click on next button its as to navigate for second page(i,e is having portlet B).

Can you please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the contextual event to handle the button click on first portlet and from there you can navigate to the second page programmatically.